# Siri-like service on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, android

Is it possible to get Siri-like voice feedback in Rasbian on the Raspberry Pi?  I know that this is available in Android, but I'm looking for options available to the Raspberry Pi.

I would like to hear responses to my own queries to the system using my voice.

Comment: Voice response from what program? Is this something you are programming? if so in what language? Asking if you should use Raspbian or Android on a site dedicated to the Pi seems like it would generate biased answers. You have not given us any details about what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your question and add these details to your question, not the comments. If all you want is your computer to speak a phrase you give it (or some text) you can try cowsay.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's [Alexa](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app) can be built on the Raspberry Pi. It uses Alexa Voice Service ([AVS](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service)). Raspberry Pi put out an article called "[Amazon Echo - The Homebrew Version](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/amazon-echo-homebrew-version/)" with a video guide describing the process.

There are probably many solutions to your questions, which could make this seem opinion based, but at this time Raspberry Pi has released an article and video describing the process, making it a pretty easy entry-level way of interacting with a Raspberry Pi over voice.

[Others](https://oscarliang.com/raspberry-pi-voice-recognition-works-like-siri/) have used [Google's Speech API scripts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?uid=19416&f=38&t=27290&start=0) to process voice and perform custom actions depending upon the commands given.